# SQL how to translate multiple columns?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table A as a 'dictionary':

```
A   type   code    name
    1      a       x
    1      b       y
    2      a       z
    2      b       t
```

I want to translate the following table B in to names:

```
B   c1     c2
    a      a
    a      b
    b      b
```

Where B.c1 is the code of A.type=1 and B.c2 is the code of A.type=2.

The expected result is

```
x    z
x    t
y    t
```

If there is only one column in B needs to be translated, it is easy.

```
SELECT A.name
 FROM  A, B
WHERE  A.type = 1
  AND  B.c1=A.code
```

Comment: Hard to understan what is Your idea. Did You know 'pivot' concept?

Comment: @JacekCz No. I am absolutely new to sql.

Comment: Can you post a sample data and expected the result?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using joins;

```
select a1.type,b.c1,a2.type,b.c2 from b
left outer join a as a1 on b.c1= a1.code and a1.type=1
left outer join a as a2 on b.c2= a2.code and a2.type=2
```

Comment: Using _joins_, not _join statements_.